# How to release an NFT collection on Cardano?

Tags: nft, minting

I come form EVM background and now I'm looking at Cardano ecosystem. From what I can see, the approach is fundamentally different when releasing NFTs. On EVM you deploy a smart contract on which users can call a mint function to obtain an NFT. On Cardano the contract is already there and you just register your NFTs into it.

I've seen a few tutorials on how to release NFTs on Cardano, but there's still one thing I don't get. How do I make NFTs available for users on the primary market? On EVM, like I mentioned above, users just mint the tokens themselves right form my contract. On Cardano, at least form what I saw in the tutorials, NFTs are minted up front by the owner.

What's the default approach to make it possible for the users to buy the NFTs for ADA. Is there a simple solution to let the users mint NFTs themselves for ADA? Or should I mint the NFT collection myself and put them in one of the stores? Please bare in mind that the collection will be pretty numerous.

I'd be grateful for pointing me to any useful resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFTs (and tokens) are native assets on Cardano and do not need separate contracts to manage them. They can be sent/received just as ADA can be (and need to be sent along with some ADA).

More info here: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/ - This also discusses how to mint an NFT and has example code.

Not all wallets can handle native assets, so maybe start with Nami wallet as it makes things easy - https://namiwallet.io/

In terms of minting a stack of new NFTs there are services like https://www.nft-maker.io/ which offer APIs and will mint on demand for you (for a small fee).

Also look at NFT market places like https://www.jpg.store/ and https://cnft.io/ for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to orchestrate mint NFTs on demand without nft-maker and without creating a dedicated smart contract?

Comment: One way to do that would be 1) Website sells/reserves NFT with a unique decimal price eg ADA12.341202 (NFT reserved for 20 mins, 341202 is the unique ID/ref). 2) User sends ADA 3) Your back-end notices the received ADA, mints the NFT and sends it back to the sending address along with 2ADA. Step 1 should log details into your DB for reference and matching. You'll notice that most of this is off-chain, only minting and sending are on-chain, so less fees and on-chain congestion.